# google reCaptcha im using ui.router in second im getting error in angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, nodes

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of null    at Object.wo [as getResponse] (recaptcha__en.js:302)   at m.$scope.acessCode (app.js:66)     at fn (eval at compile (angular.min.js:1), :4:218)

```
var captchaResponse = grecaptcha.getResponse();
console.log(captchaResponse);
if(captchaResponse.length == 0) {
    alert("Please verify the captcha before proceeding further.");
    return false;
}
```

Comment: please help me im not able to fix that bug past 4days.

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Please add some of your code to help us understand the problem.

Comment: js file related to captcha

Comment: var captchaResponse = grecaptcha.getResponse();
        console.log(captchaResponse);
        if(captchaResponse.length == 0)
        {
          alert("Please verify the captcha before proceeding further.");
          return false;
        }

Comment: captcha.html     <div no-captcha

                g-recaptcha-response="gRecaptchaResponse"
                theme='light'
                control="noCaptchaControl"
                site-key="">
              </div>

Comment: Hi again Raghu.

Seems like you have some problem in the communication. You get an empty response back. If you're using Chrome you could press F12 and open up the developer tools and look at the specific request sent and the response back. Maybe you get an error with more information that could help you?

Comment: Another think you could do is console.log(grecaptcjha) in order to see why it's empty? If your following a guide, check that you haven't forgotten to supply keys or verification. Most often you need to supply a site key or api key.

Answer (score 0):

ui.router will load the widget again so I suspect your issue is when you call vcRecaptchaService.getResponse();

As it is mentioned here https://github.com/VividCortex/angular-recaptcha/issues/81

> getResponse() has a argument that must be passed to it, the widgetId,
>   when multiple recaptcha widgets are registered/on the same page. Since
>   you have a SPA, even though the first widget is no longer there, it is
>   still registered in Google's code.

Your solution is to create a callback function in your controller

```
   $scope.createCallback = function(widgetId){
      $scope.widgetId = widgetId;
    };
```

Then when creating recaptcha call the function on create

```
 <div vc-recaptcha key="'key'" on-create="createCallback(widgetId)"></div>
```

And then back to your controller pass the widgetId when trying to getresponse

```
$scope.Response = vcRecaptchaService.getResponse($scope.widgetId);
```